# Adding List of tasks without executing

Tags: c#, task

I have a method which returns a task, which I want to call multiple times and wait for any 1 of them to be successful.  The issue I am facing is as soon as I add the task to the List, it executes and since I added delay to simulate the work, it just block there.

Is there a way to add the the tasks to the list without really executing it and let whenAny execute the tasks.

The below code is from Linqpad editor.

```
async void  Main()
{
    var t = new Test();
    List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>>();

    for( int i =0; i <  5; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(t.Getdata());
    }

    var result = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

    result.Dump();
}

public class Test
{
   public Task<int> Getdata()
   {
      "In Getdata method".Dump();
      Task.Delay(90000).Wait();
      return Task.FromResult(10);
   }
}
```

Update :: Below one makes it clear, I was under the impression that if GetData makes a call to network it will get blocked during the time it actually completes.

```
async void Main()
{
 OverNetwork t = new OverNetwork();
 List<Task<string>> websitesContentTask = new List<Task<string>>();
 websitesContentTask.Add(t.GetData("http://www.linqpad.net"));
 websitesContentTask.Add(t.GetData("http://csharpindepth.com"));
 websitesContentTask.Add(t.GetData("http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/"));
 Task<string> completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(websitesContentTask);
 string output = await completedTask;
 Console.WriteLine(output);
}

public class OverNetwork
{
    private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public Task<string> GetData(string uri)
    {
        return client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> since I added delay to simulate the work, it just block there

Actually, your problem is that your code is calling `Wait`, [which blocks the current thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx) until the delay is completed.

To properly use `Task.Delay`, you should use `await`:

```
public async Task<int> Getdata()
{
  "In Getdata method".Dump();
  await Task.Delay(90000);
  return 10;
}
```

> Is there a way to add the the tasks to the list without really executing it and let whenAny execute the tasks.

No. `WhenAny` never executes tasks. Ever.

It's possible to build a list of asynchronous delegates, i.e., a `List<Func<Task>>` and execute them later, but I don't think that's what you're really looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have read your book.  Task.Delay is just to simulate work, I could have used Thread.Sleep() but my point is ---  for example it that method Getdata() is going over the network to fetch some data , in that case when I add the task to the list, will it actually wait for the network call to complete?  I cannot await individual getData calls, I want to just add them to the list and let one of them complete and get the results.

Comment: Tasks complete when their async methods complete. So, when `Getdata` completes, the task it returns will complete.

Comment: Think I got the answer, I think this one makes it very clear.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple tasks in your `Getdata` method. First does delay, but you are returning finished task which returned 10. Try to change your code like this

```
return Task.Delay(90000).ContinueWith(t => 10)
```

Comment: the delay is not the issue, I added that to see if I call t.GetData() it actually is a blocking call.

Comment: `Getdata` is not an async method, it has to be executed to return `Task` object or any other object. If you don't want to execute it, rewrite `Getdata` method to return pure `int` and then call `tasks.Add(new Task(() => Getdata()))`. Or `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Getdata())` if you want to start execution but don't block current thread.